# Unity working with Async and Await in Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

I'm implementing a little game with Unity which use firebase services. I had a little problem with Firebase RealtimeDataBase.
I have a method "UpdateScoreAsync", this method publish the new player's record on database. Now I call this method with a code like this:

```
await UpdateScoreAsync();
LoadScene("ReloadActualScene"); // It starts the game again.
```

It works well, but like you could see in code, the new scene is loaded when the score is totally updated. My goal is load the new scene while the score is updating but if I just remove the "await" the game break when the scene is reloaded. I see my device's log (Android) and I think the problem is this:

> Native thread exiting without having called DetachCurrentThread (maybe it's going to use a pthread_key_create destructor?) (etc)

The object of UpdateScoreAsync method is a singleton and it doesn't destroy when the scene is reload. Althoug the game cracks, the score is updated on database!

My current method "UpdateScoreAsync" is like this:

```
public async Task UpdateScoreAsync(string userId, int newScore)
{
    Debug.Log("Actualizando puntuación en la base de datos...");
    await FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("string").Child("string").Child("Score").SetValueAsync(newScore).ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.IsFaulted) {
            ...
        } else if (task.IsCanceled) {
            ...
        } else if (task.IsCompleted) {
            Debug.Log("Score updated");
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

I try to change this method like this one:

```
public void UpdateScoreAsync(string userId, int newScore)
{
    Debug.Log("Actualizando puntuación en la base de datos..."); 
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("string").Child("string").Child("Score").SetValueAsync(newScore).ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.IsFaulted) {
           ...
        } else if (task.IsCanceled) {
           ...
        } else if (task.IsCompleted) {
           Debug.Log("Score updated");
           ...
        }
    });
}
```

And the call to this method:

```
UpdateScoreAsync();
LoadScene("ReloadActualScene");
```

With this new code I obtain the error I explained before. Could anyone help me?? I don't know where is the error.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Per the Unity documentation for LoadScene():

Note: Since loading is set to complete in the next rendered frame, calling SceneManager.LoadScene forces all previous AsynOperations to complete, even if AsyncOperation.allowSceneActivation is set to false. This can be avoided by using LoadSceneAsync instead.

Try using LoadSceneAsync instead.

Comment: But if I don’t understand bad, with this what I do is that the scene doesn’t load until the other async operations are finished. But I want load new scene while the other operations are executing in background, event I should be able to play in the new scene while async operations (throws in the previous scene) are still executing.

Comment: Did you try this way out?  Did it work?  If not, what happened?

Comment: I will try next week! Just now my computer is broken. I will post again when I test it! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I’m afraid that the mistake continues... :( The error is: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast. Any idea what the problem is??

Comment: That looks like a different error message then you were receiving before, correct?